# Append to list from another list

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have list like

```
list = ['1,2,3,4,5', '6,7,8,9,10']
```

I have problem with "," in list, because `'1,2,3,4,5'` its string.

I want to have `list2 = ['1','2','3','4'...]`

How i can do this?

Comment: Take closer look at str's `split` method: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be something like that:

```
nums = []
for str in list:
 nums = nums + [int(n) for n in str.split(',')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through and split the strings up.

```
list = ['1,2,3,4,5', '6,7,8,9,10']
result = []

for s in list:
    result += s.split(',')
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Split each value in the original by `,` and then keep appending them to a new list.

```
l = []
for x in ['1,2,3,4,5', '6,7,8,9,10']:
    l.extend(y for y in x.split(','))
print(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) with `map`:

```
from itertools import chain

lst = ['1,2,3,4,5', '6,7,8,9,10']

print(list(chain.from_iterable(map(lambda x: x.split(','), lst))))
# ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']
```

Note that you shouldn't use `list` name for variables as it's a built-in.

Answer (score 0):

```
list2 = []
list2+=(','.join(list).split(','))
','.join(list) produces a string of '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10'
','.join(list).split(',') produces  ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']
```

join method is used to joined elements in a list by a delimiter. It returns a string in which the elements of sequence have been joined by ','.
split method is used to split a string into a list by a delimiter. It splits a string into an array of substrings.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use list comprehension

```
li =  ['1,2,3,4,5', '6,7,8,9,10']
res = [c for s in li for c in s.split(',') ]
print(res)
#['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Without using loops
li =  ['1,2,3,4,5', '6,7,8,9,10']
p = ",".join(li).split(",")
#['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']
```